# How to set ActionMode LayoutParams to make custom view match_parent?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, layoutparams, actionmode

I'm trying to set a custom view into an ActionMode, but it doesn't match ActionMode as parent. In comparison with the standard ActionBar, when you are setting a custom view you can specifiy layout params, while is not provided in ActionMode.

There´s any solution?

```
  mode.setCustomView(mModeActionBarView);

  getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customActionBarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you get solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I finally managed it, using a xml FrameLayout (as the root view) with its width and height as match_parent, within you will add all your custom views. Then just add it as normal, `setCustomView(your_custom_ayout)`. Hope it works! @SandeepMaram

Comment: Call setCustomView on actionBar or on mode? If on mode then the solution from the comment doesn't work

Comment: Call it on actionBar. As you can see in the comment, I'm calling getSupportActionBar() which is actually the actionBar instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, too.
Solved by add 2 params to the inflater like this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_event_custom_actionbar,
                    new LinearLayout(mContext), false);
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // enable to display custom view in actionbar
 actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
 actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // remove app icon
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // remove app title
```

Comment: Is not working. Is just about ActionMode..I think. Maybe is just not supported. Seems like

Comment: can you more elaborate how you actually doing with custom view

Comment: I just inflate the custom layout. The standard way. Then I set it into the action mode.